# Bit-Shifting to find the Page Table Entry for a given Virtual Address in Linux

Tags: linux, kernel, paging

I'm working with a simplified build of Linux 3.18.20, and I need to create two new system calls: one that reads a page table entry for a given virtual address, and one that writes a page table entry corresponding to a given virtual address.  I've been using the Intel Architecture Reference Manual, Vol. 3, Chapter 4, Section 5, to understand how virtual addresses are converted to physical addresses, and in order to implement my system calls, I've created a helper function that returns the virtual address of the requested page table entry (or NULL, if that page table entry doesn't exist).

I've created a test program that creates a local variable (presumably stored on the stack, correct?) and passes its virtual address to my system call, to make sure my translation is done correctly.  I then do all the bit shifting by hand, to ensure that my code does what I think it does; and it seems to be correct, so the only conclusion I can come to at this point is that I don't know what I don't know; I need a crucial piece of information that I didn't even realize I needed.

Can you look at my code and tell me if there's something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

```
unsigned long *find_pte(unsigned long vaddr) {
    unsigned long cr3, pml4_addr, pml4e, pml4e_addr;
    unsigned long pdpt_addr, pdpte_addr, pdpte;
    unsigned long pd_addr, pde_addr, pde;
    unsigned long pt_addr, pte_addr;
    unsigned long vaddr30thru38, vaddr39thru47, vaddr21thru29, vaddr12thru20;

    cr3 = (unsigned long) get_pagetable();
    /* get_pageable() is a helper function, provided by my professor,
    that supposedly returns the contents of the CR3 register, with the most
    significant and least significant 12 bits replaced with 0.*/
    printk("in syscall: vaddr=%lx, cr3=%lx\n", vaddr, cr3);//DEBUG
    pml4_addr = cr3;
    vaddr39thru47 = (vaddr >> 36) & 0xff8;
    printk("in syscall: vaddr39thru47=%lx\n", vaddr39thru47);//DEBUG
    pml4e_addr = pml4_addr | vaddr39thru47;
    printk("in syscall: physical pml4e_addr=%lx\n", pml4e_addr);//DEBUG
    pml4e_addr = (unsigned long) __va(pml4e_addr);
    printk("in syscall: virtual pml4e_addr=%lx\n", pml4e_addr);//DEBUG
    pml4e = *((unsigned long*) pml4e_addr);
    printk("in syscall: pml4e=%lx\n", pml4e);//DEBUG
    if ((pml4e & 1) == 0) {
            printk("in syscall: pml4e's valid bit is not set\n");//DEBUG
            return NULL;
    }
    printk("in syscall: pml4e's valid bit is set\n");//DEBUG

    vaddr30thru38 = (vaddr >> 27) & 0xff8;
    printk("in syscall: vaddr30thru38=%lx\n", vaddr30thru38);
    pdpte_addr = (pdpt_addr | vaddr30thru38);
    printk("in syscall: physical pdpte_addr=%lx\n", pdpte_addr);//DEBUG
    pdpte_addr = (unsigned long) __va(pdpte_addr);
    printk("in syscall: virtual pdpte_addr=%lx\n", pdpte_addr);//DEBUG
    pdpte = *((unsigned long*) pdpte_addr);
    printk("in syscall: pdpte=%lx\n", pdpte);//DEBUG
    if (((pdpte >> 7) & 1) == 1) {
            printk("in syscall: pdpte's ps flag is 1\n");//DEBUG
            return (unsigned long*) pdpte_addr;
    }
    printk("in syscall: pdpte's ps flag is 0\n");//DEBUG
    if ((pdpte & 1) == 0) {
            printk("in syscall: pdpte's valid bit is not set\n");//DEBUG
            return NULL;
    }
    printk("in syscall: pdpte's valid bit is set\n");//DEBUG
    pd_addr = pdpte & 0x000ffffffffff000;
    printk("in syscall: pd_addr=%lx\n", pd_addr);//DEBUG
    vaddr21thru29 = (vaddr >> 18) & 0xff8;
    printk("in syscall: vaddr21thru29=%lx\n", vaddr21thru29);//DEBUG
    pde_addr = pd_addr | vaddr21thru29;
    printk("in syscall: physical pde_addr=%lx\n", pde_addr);//DEBUG
    pde_addr = (unsigned long) __va(pde_addr);
    printk("in syscall: virtual pde_addr=%lx\n", pde_addr);//DEBUG
    pde = *((unsigned long*) pde_addr);
    printk("in syscall: pde=%lx\n", pde);//DEBUG
    if (((pde >> 7) & 1) == 1) {
            printk("in syscall: pde's ps flag is 1\n");//DEBUG
            return (unsigned long*) pde_addr;
    }
    printk("in syscall: pde's ps flag is 0\n");//DEBUG
    if ((pde & 1) == 0) {
            printk("in syscall: pde's valid bit is not set\n");//DEBUG
            return NULL;
    }
    printk("in syscall: pde's valid bit is set\n");//DEBUG
    pt_addr = pde & 0x000ffffffffff000;
    printk("in syscall: pt_addr=%lx\n", pt_addr);//DEBUG
    vaddr12thru20 = (vaddr >> 9) & 0xff8;
    printk("in syscall: vaddr12thru20=%lx\n", vaddr12thru20);//DEBUG
    pte_addr = pt_addr | vaddr12thru20;
    printk("in syscall: physical pte_addr=%lx\n", pte_addr);//DEBUG
    pte_addr = (unsigned long) __va(pte_addr);
    return (unsigned long*) pte_addr;
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind.  There's nothing wrong with my code (except for the omission of one line, which was a mistake in copying the code from my file to Stack Overflow).  My test was incorrectly labelling it as broken.